# Can I use the following Fail2ban jail with my wordpress on nginx server?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, fail2ban

```
[nginx-noscript]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = nginx-noscript
logpath  = /var/log/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 6
```

It is advised to not enable [nginx-noscript] jail, if server is running scripts. What are the types of scripts in this case?

Comment: That depends on what's in the filter, which you didn't show.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the failregex definition for the `nginx-noscript` filter. You can typically find filters in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/`.

Example:

```
cat /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-noscript.conf
```

You may see something like this, which would restrict access to `.php`, `.asp`, `.exe`, `.pl`, `.cgi`, and `.scgi` files:

```
# Noscript filter /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-noscript.conf:
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*GET.*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl|\.cgi|\.scgi)
ignoreregex =
```